# .NET SqlClient Error Number Enum Type

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have an exception handler for the type SqlException and I'm looking at the SqlException.Number property of the exception to determine if a dead-lock occurred (1205). I'm currious, instead of writing SqlException.Number == 1205, is there an enum I can refer to that would produce something similar to SqlException.Number == SqlExceptionNumberEnum.DeadLockVictim?

It may not be feasible due to the shear volume of potential error messages/numbers but thought it was worth asking. Thanks!

Comment: Start your own Enum and use in your code for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. In particular, you can define your own error numbers with `sp_addmessage`, and the errors change (grow) per SQL-Server version, so it would quickly be a problem if (for example) you were using .NET 2.0 with SQL Server 2008, as your numbers would exist.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think this is feasible.  If you run the following query,

```
select * from sys.messages where language_id=1033 and severity between 11 and 16
```

it produces over six thousand rows.  You could write a small app to parse the table and produce a C# class with const properties representing each message, but it's probably not worth the effort.